# Android Twitter login not working with Fabric SDK - Callback must not be null

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

I'm working on a feature that needs to access the public data of Twitter users through the Twitter REST API, and I'm using Twitter's Fabric SDK for logging into Twitter. Here is the code of my `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_twitter_settings);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    buttonLogin = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);

    TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();

    if(session == null)
    {
        login();
    }
    else
    {
        long userid = session.getUserId();
        logout(userid);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    btnLogin.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition( R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_right);
}

private void login(){
    buttonLogin.setText("Login");
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doLogin();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void logout(long userID){
    buttonLogin.setText("Logout");
    buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doLogout();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void doLogin(){

    buttonLogin.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // ... do something
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // ... do something
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void doLogout(){

    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT).create();
    } else {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    }

    alertDialog.setTitle("Logout");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure ?");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.twitter);

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             Twitter.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();

}
```

After following all the instructions [here](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login), I keep getting the following exception when I click on the `TwitterLoginButton`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Callback must not be null.
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:67)
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(TwitterLoginButton.java:138)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, we make the stupidest mistakes. The `Callback<TwitterSession>` object needs to be set BEFORE the user clicks on the `TwitterLoginButton`. Add the following code to your `onCreate()` or `onActivityCreated()` or `onResume()` method:

```
buttonLogin.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
        // ... do something
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        // ... do something
    }
});
```

The mistake was that I had put this code in the Twitter button click listener, which is wrong naturally. You need to set the callback *before* the button is clicked, not *after*.

Comment: and how did you go about that?

Comment: I tried to use your code with your edit but when I click the button, it keeps going to twitter for permission. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: please elaborate what you mean by "going to Twitter for permission"

Comment: The permission page of twitter which asks "Is your app should be allowed to use your twitter account?"

Comment: Yes so that is correct. It needs the user's permission before it can log in.