# Android Fabric - Null pointer exception : button in popup window layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, twitter, popupwindow, twitter-fabric

I am using the Fabric plugin. I just want to embed a Twitter login Button in a popup window whose layout is in a separate XML layout file, containing the login button.

The login button is defined in the following function which is called inside the `onCreate()` function of the activity initiating it but logcat alert me the null pointer exception in the ***loginButton***.

Sure there is not problem in the id of the button in the XML. What's wrong with that?

Thanks in advance!

```
private void TwitterLoginBtn() {

btn_twitter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter);

btn_twitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.twitter_login, null);
        TWin = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //LinearLayout popLayout = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.twitter_login, null);

        //TWin = new PopupWindow(ShotActivity1.this);

        //TWin.setContentView(popLayout);

        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter_login);

        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
                TwitterSession session = result.data;
                // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
                // with your app's user model
                String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
            }
        });


        Button btn_closeTwitter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_closeT);

        btn_closeTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                TWin.dismiss();

            }
        });

        TWin.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        TWin.showAsDropDown(v, 0, 0);


    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `Callback<TwitterSession>` object **before** the user clicks on the TwitterLoginButton `loginButton`

So, take this:

```
loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_twitter_login);

    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // The TwitterSession is also available through:
            // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
            // with your app's user model
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
        }
    });
```

And put it on **onCreate()** method. I remembered that reading again [Android Twitter login not working with Fabric SDK - Callback must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184070/android-twitter-login-not-working-with-fabric-sdk-callback-must-not-be-null)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ya, it helps. I dun even know that but the logcat said the button itself is null. I wonder why.

Comment: If it is correct, could you mark it as the right answer? I think you are trying to add a custom buttom, right? I might not work, use the original twitter buttom. Maybe you are clicking on your custom buttom before you declare the twitterbuttom...